# How to submit an HTML Post Request with JMeter to an oracle-apex website

Tags: ajax, jmeter, oracle-apex

I am encountering an issue with Jmeter when attempting to stress test an oracle apex website. The issue I'm having is stemming from an ajax issue.

With Jmeter I am trying to simulate a button click on page one of an application with an HTTP Post Request on the page:

```
/Capps/wwv_flow.ajax
```

I am passing in the following variables:

```
p_flow_id         101
p_flow_step_id    1
p_instance        ${sessionid}
p_request         PLUGIN=ijiPvZ-iJYfT0ihaQKUMZz3Lcjg8SHOXpMeHDzckC5k
p_json            {"pageItems":null,"salt":"258015622351528748546171137179439761614"}
```

The first three are the applicaiton number, page number, and sessionid (the sessionid was retrieved in a earlier step using a regex extractor) Also, the p_request and p_json are encoded.

I noticed from using chrome in developer mode that the p_request string and 
 the last part of the p_json string often change with each run through of the button click

I was unable to find any information online that could help explain this occurs so that I could find a solution to simulate the button click.

Note I am having a similar issue on another page where I attempt to submit a simple form.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you,

Zac

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Configuring Apache JMeter for Apex](http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com/2010/05/configuring-apache-jmeter-for-apex.html) article it seems you need to correlate these `p_request` and `p_json` parameters in exactly the same manner as you do for `p_instance` (assuming different relevant [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) of course)

Alternatively you can record your test scenario using a cloud-based proxy tool which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automated correlation of all detected dynamic parameters applied, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `p_request` remaining the same and substituting the salt value with the `p_page_submission_id` value, which comes in response of the Application launch call.

This worked for me.